# Can I hide a particular subquestion or answer using Expression Manager in Limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I need to hide an answer of a List (radio) question type and a subquestion of a Multiple choice question type. I need to use the Expression Manager syntax for this like

{if( V001.NAOK != 'A1', 'The answer /subquestion', 'Hide the answer /subquestion' )}

in the Answer / Subquestion textbox option in the Edit answer options page / Edit subquestions page;
where V001 is the first question code & A1 is one of its Answer / Subquestion code.
I need to hide the answer /subquestion of the second question using Expression Manager syntax because Expression Manager syntax is easy and the client dont know javascript .

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No simple solution .... without javascript : use ARRAY filter and system like that : http://demonstration.sondages.pro/676785.html

Comment: Hi Denis Chenu,

Thanks for your reply.

I am using Limesurvey 2.05. Please tell me how to hide  blank  subquestions / answers  in 2.05  of  List (radio) and Multiple choice question type. So I  can use 

{if( V001.NAOK != 'A1',  'The answer /subquestion',  '' )}

which results in blank  subquestion / answer.

Thank you very much.